# Flask's test_client() is not passing custom HTTP Headers to the Flask app

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I have something like this in my test script:

```
def setUp(self):
    app = create_app()
    self.app = app.test_client()

def test_001(self):

    with self.app as app:
        headers = { 'API-KEY': 'myKey' }            
        app.get('/endpoint1', follow_redirects=True,headers=headers)
```

Reading through the print statements from my application, I can see that my application endpoint is called, and things look normal except for the header missing from the request.

In my API, I have this print statement:

```
log("Headers: " + str(request.headers))
```

This output the following messages in the console:

```
Headers: User-Agent: werkzeug/0.14.1
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 0
```

So apparently, the client does send some headers, but not the custom one I added.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong, that causes the headers either not to be sent in the first place, or them not being accessible to the server?

Comment: `self.app = create_app()` and try `client = app.test_client()`
instead of `self.app = app.test_client()` and then `client.get()` and you need `app.config['TESTING'] = True`

Answer (score 0):

```
def setUp(self):
    self.app = create_app()
    self.app.config['TESTING'] = True
    self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
    self.app_context.push()
    self.client = self.app.test_client()

def test_001(self):
    headers = { 'API-KEY': 'myKey' }            
    response = self.client.get('/endpoint1', follow_redirects=True, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling:
using `follow_redirects=True` somehow looses the headers on redirect.

Simple workaround is to do the redirect yourself:

```
headers = { 'KEY': '123' }
code = 301
url = '/v1/endpoint'

while code == 301:
    response = client.get(url, headers=headers)
    code = response._status_code
    if code == 301: #'Location' is only in header if 301
        url = response.headers['Location']
```